# How to add the elements by focusing with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic, addition, element

I would like to use jquery to build a dynamic add form.

I want to add a new div when focus on the end of last text input(third text input).

> js & html files

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.content:last span input.pdate").focus(function() {
    var lastDiv = $(".content:last");
    var newDiv = lastDiv.clone();
    /* debugger;
     num_of_product = num_of_product +1;
    newDiv.find("#num_of_product").innerText=num_of_product;
    console.log($(newDiv.find("#num_of_product").innerText)); */
    lastDiv.after(newDiv);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <label for="pname">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Product Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|</label>
  <label for="pprice">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Product Price&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|</label>
  <label for="pdate">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Product Date</label>
</div>


<div class="content" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <span id="num-of-product" style=" position: relative;left: -50px; top: 20px;"></span>
  <span style="margin-left: 10px; position: relative;left: -50px; top: 20px;">
    <input type="text" style="padding:2px; margin: 0 auto;width: 180px;height: 35px;" class="pname">
  </span>
  <span style="margin-left: 10px; position: relative;left: -1px; top: 20px;">
    <input type="text" style="padding:2px;margin: 0 auto; width: 150px;height: 35px;" class="pprice">
  </span>
  <span style="margin-left: 10px; position: relative;left: 56px; top: 20px;">
    <input type="text" style=" margin: 0 auto;padding:2px; width: 150px;height: 35px;" class="pdate">
  </span>
  <br class="clear">
</div>
```

> output

[ui of html code (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QRg7.png)

when focusing on the first, third element(text input) intended div will be added; while i want to add **the third element from the Previous row after focusing it**.

Any help and tips on this are appreciated.

Comment: `$("div.content:last span input.pdate").focus(...)` is only executed once, hence the only element with a focus handler is the "last" `div.content` element at the time of execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event binding from `focus` was only being applied to the element present in the DOM when the call was made. This change will now unbind and bind the events when each new row is added.

```js
function addRow() {
  var lastDiv = $(".content:last");
  var newDiv = lastDiv.clone();
  lastDiv.after(newDiv);
  $("div.content span input.pdate").off('focus', addRow);
  $("div.content:last span input.pdate").on('focus', addRow);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.content:last span input.pdate").focus(addRow);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <label for="pname">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Product Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|</label>
  <label for="pprice">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Product Price&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|</label>
  <label for="pdate">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Product Date</label>
</div>


<div class="content" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <span id="num-of-product" style=" position: relative;left: -50px; top: 20px;"></span>
  <span style="margin-left: 10px; position: relative;left: -50px; top: 20px;">
    <input type="text" style="padding:2px; margin: 0 auto;width: 180px;height: 35px;" class="pname">
  </span>
  <span style="margin-left: 10px; position: relative;left: -1px; top: 20px;">
    <input type="text" style="padding:2px;margin: 0 auto; width: 150px;height: 35px;" class="pprice">
  </span>
  <span style="margin-left: 10px; position: relative;left: 56px; top: 20px;">
    <input type="text" style=" margin: 0 auto;padding:2px; width: 150px;height: 35px;" class="pdate">
  </span>
  <br class="clear">
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of constantly adding and removing an event handler, use event delegation